# eloquent filter result based on foreign table attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-collection

I'm using laravel and eloquent.
Actually I have problems filtering results from a table based on conditions on another table's attributes.
I have 3 tables:

- venue
- city

  here are the relationships:
  a `city` has many `locations` and a `location` belongs to a `city`.
  a `location` belongs to a `venue` and a `venue` has one `location`.

I have a `city_id` attribute on locations table, which you may figured out from relationships.

The question is simple:
how can I get those venues which belong to a specific city?
the eloquent query I expect looks like this:
`$venues=Venue::with('location')->where('location.city_id',$city->getKey());`

Of course that's not gonna work, but seems like this is common task  and there would be an **eloquent** command for it.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried HasManythrough? a city has many venues through locations. Access a distant relation through a related eloquent model?

Comment: @mdamia this kink a relationship is belongsToManyThrough which isn't implemented in laravel eloquent yet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
$venues = Venue::whereIn('location_id', Location::whereCityId($city->id)->get->lists('id'))
    ->get();
```

Or possibly using `whereHas`:

```
$venues = Venue::whereHas('location', function($query) use ($city) {
    $query->whereCityId($city->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: god bless you! second one worked like a charm. but my question has two parts which I didn't mention the second part here. I have a Tag model which has a many to many relation with Venue. given a string of Tag name how can filter that as well? should I create another question for it?

Comment: Just figured out whereHas expects a relationship as a first argument so  this worked as well `->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {
    $query->whereName($tag);
   })`

Comment: how's the approximate performance of this query, is it efficient to query this way for multiple times?

Comment: It should be really good if your indexes are good. Generated SQL of a test query I just ran was: `select * from companies where (select count(*) from locations where locations.company_id = companies.id and id = ?) >= 1`, so it actually created a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that each eloquent query returns a collection, and hence you can use "[collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-values)" on the result. So as said in other answers, you need a [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) which you ask for the attribute you want to sort on from another table based on your relationship and then on the result, which is a collection, you either use "sortBy" or "sortByDesc" methods.

You can look at an example below:

```
class Post extends Model {
        // imagine timpestamp table: id, publish, delete,
        // timestampable_id, timestampble_type
    public function timestamp()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Timestamp::class, 'timestampable');
    }
}
```

and then in the view side of the stuff:

```
$posts = App\Post::with('timestamp')->get(); // we make Eager Loading
$posts = $posts->sortByDesc('timestamp.publish');
return view('blog.index', compact('posts'));
```